# Why this piece of TypeScript code got a type error?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Options<
  TData,
  TMethod,
  TComputed extends Record<string, (data: TData) => any>
> = {
  computed?: TComputed;
  data?: TData;
  methods?: TMethod
} &
ThisType<{
  data: TData & {
    [K in keyof TComputed]: ReturnType<TComputed[K]>
  }
} & TMethod>

function Card<
  TData extends Record<string, any> = {},
  TMethod extends Record<string, Function> = {},
  TComputed extends Record<string, (data: TData) => any> = {}
>(options: Options<TData, TMethod, TComputed>) {
  
}

Card({
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  computed: {
    c(data) { // got type error, the param data type can't be inferred.
      return data.a + 1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    bar() {
      this.data.c
    },
    say() {
      this.bar();
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgFBSgFQBEBDYIgGh3wFkJgALJAEwtzwGEkBbMAV2AkZQIAD34pGaKACUIAYyQAnRhjTAFCFAHMyUABSMSRAFz5ipAJRQAvAD4oRFCBtY7VqAG9K87nwEB+E3YuXn5GAG5KA1IA00MI3E5aBgkYvBp6JiwAXygAMiw8OgQ0PHAIDE9cKONY0jyPSlwAbQBpKA0oAGsIECQAM3wOH1CAXRMZYB4FFFLIDCDhgVaR51ws7Pq0pKZnLD6eFFlEVCg2IiVsVjMiIVEIcUkZeQvVdS0dBydrDyyWam3BCIxBJpHJFMpXhptFAAGIHI7IFCuH5-BYhAS3YGPMEvNRQnT6QyBa6WWz2RzI9zrGy6JDwRFoExwY7oebXHRbDLMQbBXyMGyWSpQbJYLBnJS6IXVExC3A1ACMlF+Xl5oRljSgskJFgauD1UAUtCmKCg1QAdDcANRQeXxPXrNZ-RJcxm6vUAI3OukFGtw9GKZvNsg1yv1aCIIG9bv1-rQZs9Cm9drWSuy5iAA)

I wrote this piece of TypeScript code and got a type error, I wander why the function in computed options can't get the correct parameter type: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7006)

Comment: please be more clear about what you expect to happen and what error you are getting

Comment: Your `TComputed` only mentions `TData` in its constraint, and constraints are not inference sites in TypeScript. (see [ms/TS#72234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)). If you want to fix this you should consider refactoring to a mapped type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wejgBN), which represents your goal even more closely, I think. Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your comment which answered my question. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `TComputed` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<string, (data: TData) => any>`, and that's the only place where `TComputed` depends on `TData`.

But TypeScript does not use generic constraints as sources for type inference (see [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)).  Constraints mostly serve to *check* a type argument that has been inferred.  So `TComputed` will be inferred from the `computed` property of the input without any contribution from `TData`.

That means there's no available [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) from which TypeScript can infer the type of the `data` callback parameter, and so it falls back to `any` [which is an error under the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#noimplicitany).

So that's why it's happening.

---

To get this working I'd suggest that you refactor so that the type of the `computed` properly explicitly depends on `TData` directly and not simply through a constraint.  You can change the call signature so that `computed` is of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over a type parameter `R` corresponding to the return values of each property of `computed`.  Like this:

```
type Options<
  TData,
  TMethod,
  R extends object
> = {
  computed?: { [K in keyof R]: { (data: TData): R[K] } };
  data?: TData;
  methods?: TMethod
} &
  ThisType<{
    data: TData & R
  } & TMethod>

function Card<
  TData extends Record<string, any> = {},
  TMethod extends Record<string, Function> = {},
  R extends object = {}
>(options: Options<TData, TMethod, R>) { }
```

Now the type of `computed` directly depends on `TData` in the proper position for contextual typing, but the individual return type for each method is captured in `R`.  Note how the `R` type is actually the underlying type you care about, and thus the type expression for `Options` is a bit simpler (you don't need to try to use the utility type [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to tease out the information).

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
Card({
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  computed: {
    c(data) { // okay
      return data.a + 1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    bar() {
      this.data.c
    },
    say() {
      this.bar();
    }
  }
})
```

Looks good.  `TData` is inferred as `{ a: number; }`, `TMethod` is inferred as `{ bar(): void; say(): void;}`, and `R` is inferred as `{ c: number; }`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgFBSgFQBEBDYIgGh3wFkJgALJAEwtwCUoIAPYCFRtKEgBGAKwgBjYFgB8UALxQA3pXFIAtmACuPRgH4AXEqgBtANJQEKKAGsIIJADMorALqHFUABSMSRQ4V8ASkNWMxcoAF9IgG5KH1IDfGJSWNw1WgZ+RLwaeiYsKIAySjw6BDQ8cAgMZVxceL8k3yhC50oi6gymaSwsB00USWQrAGEiACdGbFwA0g5uXn5nCSRJjDRgccsAczIoIhQQWQVFCJZOvMZ5nj4BVhW1ja2UXagAMQGh1GOlM8p2Lg3JbCMSSeS-GSeJDwYZoQxwRCoTCzcgXTJ7VjSQJGCK9MaTTy1KANdyUXCNACM7XOqg02ggjFJdSg4m8QSMAHoOYJrEQQGS6uNaJpxlYGgA6IhQADUUApqTquNwfzSXX4TLqQgmnmxROZ9HK4ol4gFKrqaD5OqUAtwBrQ4q14x1CuV7QKgSwHIAVFB+oNEaMJlMPI0UJo1EIIONopE9h5HTrDAA3JAIRgxi0gRNQFNp6JnIziQxhiNRmMRWRejlAA)